# How to apply the projection and modelview matrixs of QCAR (Vuforia) to min3D scene

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, qcar-sdk

I would like to use Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK (Vuforia) with the min3D library and load obj model. How can I merge QCAR (Vuforia) with min3D? How to apply the projection and modelview matrixs of QCAR (Vuforia) to min3D? So that the scene is rendered correct in min3d.glsurfaceview? Has anyone developed an example? How is your experience?

How can I apply movdelview and project matrix which was generated by QCAR in C to apply then in Min3D scene of Java? Suggest me to achieve this.any sample code which have already solved this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same but I did not succeed as the movdelview matrix that Min3d accepts is different from what Vuforia gives, so I used [jpct-ae](http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#jPCT-AE_-_a_port_of_jPCT_to_Android) instead and now I am able to load even animated Md2 models. Try Jpct and if you face problem ask.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing as @yogi said. `jPCT-AE` and `QCAR` together are awesome. I used a single `GLSurfaceView` and brought the `ModelView` matrix and the actual video resolution from native code to Java. Then you can easily load an `MD2` file along with animation.

You can watch the result here:

http://youtu.be/chsHh0pEhzw