# Decompose projection matrix44 to left, right, bottom, top, near and far boundary values

Tags: android, opengl-es, qcar-sdk

Can any one help me to get left, right, bottom, top, near and far boundary values from projection matrix44?

Answer (score 10):

Here are the resolutions of the equation systems [Christian Rau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836497/758666) referred to :

For an orthographic matrix :

```
near   =  (1+m34)/m33;
far    = -(1-m34)/m33;
bottom =  (1-m24)/m22;
top    = -(1+m24)/m22;
left   = -(1+m14)/m11;
right  =  (1-m14)/m11;
```

For a perspective matrix :

```
near   = m34/(m33-1);
far    = m34/(m33+1);
bottom = near * (m23-1)/m22;
top    = near * (m23+1)/m22;
left   = near * (m13-1)/m11;
right  = near * (m13+1)/m11;
```

You can replace the values m11, m12, etc., by the formulas defined in the documentation for [glOrtho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [glFrustum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check it's correct.

Comment: FYI this answer is using (1-indexed) row major matrix coords, OpenGL uses column major by default.

If you don't transpose the coords, `m34` will be a constant value.

Answer (score 3):

First, you could look how those matrices are defined for corresponding calls to [`glOrtho`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) and [`glFrustum`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) (or similar functions from your framework). The next steps depend on the kind of projection, being either orthographic (e.g. from `glOrtho`) or perspective (e.g. from `glFrustum` or `gluPerspective`), which can be decided by looking at the 3rd column.

Now for an orthographic matrix it is quite easy to get to the two equations:

```
right - left = 2 / m11
right + left = -2 * m14 / m11
```

From these you can quite easily compute `right = (1-m14) / m11` and `left = right - 2/m11` (you may recheck for any errors made during my mental arithmetics). And similar for the other two pairs of parameters (pay attention to the sign of `m33`).

For a perspective projection you should first compute `near` and `far` using `m33` and `m34`. Then you can compute `right/left` and `bottom/top` similar to the above case, but using the computed `near` value.

So all in all, once you know the formulas for the matrices based on the parameters, it really comes down to just a bunch of simple 2x2 equation systems easy to solve. A more interesting question would be, why you actually need to compute these parameters from a projection matrix. If you really need them, you should just store them (as you are the one who constructs the matrix, anyway). Otherwise it sounds like another instance of using OpenGL for more things (like scene management) than it's actually intended for, being just a simple drawing API.

Comment: Actually I have to do this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810360/how-to-apply-the-projection-and-modelview-matrixs-of-qcar-vuforia-to-min3d-sce). Help me to achieve.

Comment: @user779554 I don't have any experience with those libraries you're talking about, but as a general information you might not have known, you don't neccessarily need to extract the parameters of a `glOrtho` or `glFrustum` call from a matrix to get the same projection matrix into OpenGL. You can just use the `glLoadMatrix` or `glMultMatrix` functions to input matrices directly. Not sure if it's that what you want to achieve, as I didn't understand this other question completely.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, I copy here below the values of near, far, etc. in C++ for OpenGL with 0-indexed column-major projection matrix:

```
float near = m_projectionMatrix[3][2] / (m_projectionMatrix[2][2] - 1.0f);
float far = m_projectionMatrix[3][2] / (m_projectionMatrix[2][2] + 1.0f);
logStderr(VERBOSE, "near, far %5.2f, %5.2f...\n", near, far);

float nearBottom = near * (m_projectionMatrix[2][1] - 1) / m_projectionMatrix[1][1];
float nearTop = near * (m_projectionMatrix[2][1] + 1) / m_projectionMatrix[1][1];
float nearLeft = near * (m_projectionMatrix[2][0] - 1) / m_projectionMatrix[0][0];
float nearRight = near * (m_projectionMatrix[2][0] + 1) / m_projectionMatrix[0][0];
logStderr(VERBOSE, "nearLeft, nearRight, nearTop, nearBottom %5.2f, %5.2f, %5.2f, %5.2f...\n", nearLeft, nearRight, nearTop, nearBottom);

float farBottom = far * (m_projectionMatrix[2][1] - 1) / m_projectionMatrix[1][1];
float farTop = far * (m_projectionMatrix[2][1] + 1) / m_projectionMatrix[1][1];
float farLeft = far * (m_projectionMatrix[2][0] - 1) / m_projectionMatrix[0][0];
float farRight = far * (m_projectionMatrix[2][0] + 1) / m_projectionMatrix[0][0];
logStderr(VERBOSE, "farLeft, farRight, farTop, farBottom %5.2f, %5.2f, %5.2f, %5.2f...\n", farLeft, farRight, farTop, farBottom);
```